# Using SVG as React Component from Private React UI Library-(CRA) inside React app with Webpack 5 crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-4, webpack-5

I created a UI Library with CRA.
The library is published on npm.
Components in the library use SVG, which I use with the syntax of

```
import {ReactCompoent as Icon} from 'assets / icon'
```

I want to use the library inside **my main app** that I create with react 17.0.2 and webpack 5.
I add the loaders to Webpack and I can use svg as components inside Main app
as -

```
import CalendarIcon from './Calendar.svg'
```

and it works.

After I install the library and import the component that use SVG as ReactComponent:

```
import {BadgeBox} from '@privatelib/ui/lib/src'
```

the app crashes. With an error of:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@privatelib/ui/lib/src/components/BadgeBox/index.js 107:1697-1707

export 'ReactComponent' (imported as 'CloseIcon') was not found in '../../assets/sm/xsmall-icon.svg' (possible exports: default)
```

**My React UI Library:**

components:

```
import { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from '../../assets/sm/x-small-icon.svg';
```

tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "es2016"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "types": ["cypress", "cypress-file-upload"],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "custom.d.ts",
  ],
}
```

**My Main App:**

**webpack config:**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');

const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash:20].esm.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash:20].esm.js',
    hashFunction: 'xxhash64',
    pathinfo: false,
    crossOriginLoading: false,
    clean: true,
    publicPath: 'auto',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3011,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|)$/,
        type: 'asset/inline',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'sidebar',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        './SideBar': './src/components/Sidebar/index.tsx',
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

**babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-runtime"],
    "babel-plugin-styled-components"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**
The right way of importing `default` exports in JavaScript is

```
import CloseIcon from '../../assets/sm/x-small-icon.svg';
```

---

In JavaScript, the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax is as follows:

```js
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import { export1 } from "module-name";
```

which means:

- "import the component of `module-name` that is exported as `default` and use it as `defaultExport`"
- "import the component of `module-name` that is exported as `export1` and use it as such"

According to the SVGR docs *(1)*,

> Please note that by default, @svgr/webpack will try to export the React Component via default export if there is no other loader handling svg files with default export.

Translated to plain JavaScript-English, this means "as long as you do not tell us otherwise, we will export the ReactComponent as the `default`". Since you are not configuring anything different in your webpack config and trying to import the ReactComponent, I assume it should be available as the `default` export. Therefore, the right way to importing it is

```
import CloseIcon from '../../assets/sm/x-small-icon.svg';
```

This is just a guess, of course you can proof me wrong. *(2)*

---

1. *I assume you are using [@svgr/webpack](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) again, as [in your previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71820229/9969672)*
2. *Since this proposal is deducted from the docs and your code, there might be other factors involved that I'm not aware of.*