# How to add svg file as an object in react js?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, svg

I would like to ask how can I manage to add svg file as an object?

```
<svg className="home-icon icon" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 122.88 114.45" imageRendering="optimizeQuality" fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd">
    <path fillRule="nonzero" d="M110.8,107.88v4.48c0,1.16-0.94,2.09-2.09,2.09h-95.1c-1.16,0-2.09-0.94-2.09-2.09v-4.48V84.2v-25.3 c-2.34,0.9-4.53,0.92-6.35,0.3c-1.42-0.48-2.62-1.34-3.5-2.45c-0.88-1.11-1.44-2.46-1.61-3.95c-0.26-2.31,0.43-4.92,2.4-7.37l0,0 c0.1-0.12,0.21-0.24,0.34-0.34L59.85,0.55c0.74-0.68,1.88-0.75,2.7-0.11l57.19,44.46l0,0c0.09,0.07,0.17,0.14,0.25,0.23 c2.65,2.85,3.31,6.01,2.67,8.68c-0.32,1.32-0.95,2.51-1.82,3.48c-0.87,0.98-1.98,1.74-3.24,2.19c-2,0.72-4.38,0.7-6.79-0.44V84.2 V107.88L110.8,107.88z M5.57,48.23c-1.11,1.45-1.5,2.9-1.37,4.12c0.08,0.7,0.33,1.32,0.73,1.82c0.39,0.49,0.92,0.86,1.56,1.08 c1.09,0.37,2.5,0.27,4.11-0.49l49.79-37.88c0.77-0.59,1.82-0.56,2.55,0.01l0,0l48.37,37.6c0.02,0.02,0.04,0.04,0.07,0.05 c1.77,1.28,3.47,1.48,4.79,1.01c0.61-0.22,1.14-0.58,1.55-1.05c0.42-0.47,0.72-1.03,0.87-1.66c0.33-1.38-0.07-3.08-1.55-4.74 L61.27,4.74L5.57,48.23L5.57,48.23z M29.6,75.49h26.7c1.04,0,1.89,0.83,1.89,1.85v20.89c0,1.02-0.85,1.85-1.89,1.85H29.6 c-1.04,0-1.89-0.83-1.89-1.85V77.34C27.72,76.32,28.56,75.49,29.6,75.49L29.6,75.49z M67.73,73.65H92.8c1.12,0,2.03,0.94,2.03,2.1 v34.52h11.78V56.57c0-0.14,0.01-0.27,0.04-0.4L61.64,21.18L15.63,56.19c0.05,0.17,0.07,0.35,0.07,0.54v53.53h50V75.74 C65.7,74.58,66.61,73.65,67.73,73.65L67.73,73.65z M90.77,77.84h-21v32.38h21V77.84L90.77,77.84z M54.41,89.63H44.5v6.75h9.91 V89.63L54.41,89.63z M40.8,89.63h-9.31v6.75h9.31V89.63L40.8,89.63z M31.49,85.93h9.31v-6.74h-9.31V85.93L31.49,85.93z M44.5,85.93 h9.91v-6.74H44.5V85.93L44.5,85.93z M60.88,36.33c3.55,0,6.43,2.88,6.43,6.43c0,3.55-2.88,6.43-6.43,6.43 c-3.55,0-6.43-2.88-6.43-6.43C54.45,39.2,57.33,36.33,60.88,36.33L60.88,36.33z"/>
</svg>
```

I want to add this svg file to this objects:

```
export const navLinks = [
  { 
    id: "home",
    title: "Home",
    svg: //here would come the svg file
  },
  { 
    id: "contact",
    title: "Contact",
  },
];
```

So later on I could render this svg file on nav

```
{navLinks.map((nav) => (
   <li className="nav_list-item">
      {nav.svg}
      <a className="nav_link" href={`#${nav.id}`}>{nav.title}</a>
   </li>
))}
```

Comment: What bundler are you using? Assuming you are using Webpack or Vite (or maybe even NextJS) with some add-on that allows importing SVG, you could import the SVG as a component and include it in the svg property for your navLinks

[Here is a link on how to import it with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820229/import-svg-as-react-components-with-webpack-5)
[And here for vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309561/unable-to-import-svg-with-vite-as-reactcomponent)

Comment: `import { ReactComponent as homeSVG } from "../images/svg/home.svg";

export const navLinks = [
  {
    id: "home",
    svg: { homeSVG },
    title: "Home",
  },`

You mean like this? Because it does not work, it says "Objects are not valid as a React child.."